# PyQt5 Messagebox closes immediately

Tags: python, pyqt

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from config_assign_ui import Ui_ConfigAssign
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ConfigAssign):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.combo_list()
        self.ImportMapButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.import_map())
        self.ExceptButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.except_file())

    def except_file(self):
        if self.ExceptCheckBox.isChecked():
            print('will do stuff')
        else:
            mb = QMessageBox()
            mb.setWindowTitle('Error')
            mb.setText('Please check exception box first')
            mb.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            mb.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The message box opens but closes immediately when I press the button. From my research, this message box is out of scope at the end of the `__init__`, but I'm not sure what this means. I tried changing one of the lines to:

```
mb = self.QMessageBox()
```

But that results in AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'QMessageBox'. Help is always appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: change `mb.show()` to `mb.exec_()`

Comment: plus: change `self.ImportMapButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.import_map())
        self.ExceptButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.except_file())` to `self.ImportMapButton.clicked.connect(self.import_map)
        self.ExceptButton.clicked.connect(self.except_file)`

Comment: eyllanesc, thank you very much. Any tips on where I can learn these little details? I Google lots of solutions and this is the first time I've seen the exec_ recommended over show.

Comment: Read the documentation of Qt, if you do not understand C++ then you do not pay attention to the implementation but in the explanation of the function, for example the explanation of the difference between exec_() and show() is in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs

Comment: Qt uses intensively OOP and especially the inheritance, so if you analyze a class you should also read the base class, for example QMessageBox inherits from QDialog, and as you see the solution is in the base class.